# showHeaderRow=true behaviour in Firefox/IE11

Tags: slickgrid

I'm using 6pac slickgrid.
Setting **showHeaderRow=true** option makes the horizontal scroll on top of the grid

[example in 6pac version](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html).

Any idea about this ?

Behaviour is correct in the original repo :

[mleibman repo](https://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html)

thx

Comment: `.slick-header.ui-state-default, .slick-headerrow.ui-state-default, .slick-footerrow.ui-state-default, .slick-top-panel-scroller.ui-state-default, .slick-group-header.ui-state-default{
   overflow:hidden !important;
  }`
Fixed the problem

Comment: thanks for finding that. I'll have a look and try to incorporate into the CSS. I suspect perhaps inheritance is taking precedence somewhere, so it may be a parent class. On the other hand, no other browser seems to have the problem, so maybe it's a bug in FF!